Chrome/Chromium subpixel rendering: --disable-font-subpixel-positioning not working
When I start Chrome or Chromium with the --disable-font-subpixel-positioning switch, I still see subpixel rendering without a change. Why is that switch being ignored, how do I disable subpixel rendering?

I'm tempted to say that you're confusing subpixel antialiasing with subpixel positioning? Those have entirely different effects.

@grawity_u1686 The first link says that --disable-font-subpixel-positioning "affects the character glyph sharpness, kerning, hinting and layout". But I don't see any of that. Screenshot files have identical contents.
